# Elastic Search - get records by starting character of a field

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using Elastic Search Server. I need to get records based on starting character of a field value in source JSON.

### JSON:

```
Index JSON1 : "{\"id\":\"1\",\"message\":\"welcome to elastic search\"}"
Index JSON2 : "{\"id\":\"1\",\"message\":\"Hellow world\"}"
```

### Code:

```
String selectedCharacter = "w";
PrefixQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.prefixQuery("message", selectedCharacter);
builder.setQuery(queryBuilder);
```

By using the above code, I am getting both the records. **I need only 'Index JSON1'.** Please give any solution to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Elasticsearch will "tokenize" string fields.

It means that your message fields are considered as a multiple terms fields. For JSON1 : `["welcome", "to", "elastic", "search"]` and JSON2 : `["Hellow", "world"]`.

When you make your query, ElasticSearch will try to match on of the term, that's why you get JSON1 for the "welcome" term et JSON2 for the "world" term.

If you want your message field to be "untokenized" (treated as a single string), you have to explicitly set the mapping of this field to `keyword`. This is done by using the Mapping API.

You can look at :

- the keyword analyzer doc : http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/keyword-analyzer/
- the mapping API doc : http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-put-mapping/

If you need a `keyword` analyzer but case-insensitive, you need to define a custom analyzer with a `lowercase` filter (you will probably need to delete and recreate your index for that). Ex :

```
$ curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test/_settings' -d '
  {
    "index": {
      "analysis" : {
        "analyzer" : {
          "lowercaseAnalyzer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "keyword",
            "filter": ["lowercase"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And then you define your mapping with this custom analyzer instead of `keyword` :

```
"message" : {"type" : "string", "analyzer" : "lowercaseAnalyzer"}
```

You can also test your analyzer using the analyze API. Ex :

```
$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test/_analyze?analyzer=lowercaseAnalyzer&pretty=true' -d 'Hello world'
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "hello world",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 11,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  } ]
}
```

You can see all the available tokenizers and filters in the analysis documentation : http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/

Comment: I have one more doubt. After mapping the field as 'keyword', it worked fine. But it is give result as case sensitive. I need case insensitive records.

Comment: add a [lowercase filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/lowercase-tokenfilter/) ...

Comment: That's right, the keyword analyzer is case-sensitive. In your case, you will need to define a custom analyzer. I will update my answer with more info.